# What should be the type of the object constructed from the below code i.e. new TreeNode<int> (13)

Tags: c++

From the book "C++ primer", it says:

> compiler uses the initializer's type to deduce the type to allocate.

It also mentions:

> we can use `auto` to deduce the type of the object we want to allocate from that initializer.

In the below line of code, does `new TreeNode<int>(13)` return a pointer of type `int*` (since the initializer is `13`, which is `int`) or, a pointer to an object of type `TreeNode<int>`?

```cpp
template<typename T>
class TreeNode {
  T data;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;

public:
  TreeNode(T init_value) : data(init_value), left(NULL), right(NULL) { }
};

int main() {
  TreeNode<int>* main_node = new TreeNode<int>(13);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new TreeNode<int>(13)` results in a `TreeNode<int>*`.

Comment: `new TreeNode<int>(13);` returns a pointer to `TreeNode<int>`. `auto(obj)` is a special case. `auto` is not a type. It's a placeholder: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section of the book describes the behavior of the keyword `auto`. It's not the general behavior. `auto(obj)` is a special case. `auto` is not a type. It's a keyword for a placeholder: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Using `auto` the type is deduced from the object.

In `new TreeNode<int>(13);` you are using a specific type and an object of this type can be initialized with an `int`. It returns a pointer to `TreeNode<int>`.